# I want to replace specific text automatically

Tags: c++, string, replace

How to find specific text in a file and replace it, because the file is huge and doing it automatically is impossible. The part of the file I want to replace text looks like this

```
aa = printf
cc = cout
ee = scanf
```

etc (like 1000 lines of this)
Doing it with replace using a text editor is very boring and will take me days, is there a way I can replace it automatically so it looks like this?

```
printf = printf
cout = cout
scanf = scanf
```

As a coder I know I can look like someone who wants others to do the work for me, but I already searched for code and tried to do it for myself but I'm terrible with c++ :/ any help is appreciated

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use C++? You can do it in seconds with emacs (or vi, I'm sure); if you tell us how to know where this part of the file begins and ends, a sed one-liner will probably suffice.

Comment: Editor macro or sed

Comment: If your editor spends days doing a few "replace all"s on a thousand lines, or can't do "replace all", you need a better editor.

Comment: ok guys the programming language is LUA, but it's a very limited language so I thought with c++ it would be easier. file looks like this

Comment: local b = print

(does this with every single function lua has) 

Then it does:
b("test") 
This makes knowing what function the script is calling very difficult, so I would like to replace:
b("test")
With:
print("test")

Comment: if it looks very messy the code is here https://pastebin.com/XhesWQMe

Comment: @Beta can you help me with the sed?

Comment: Sure, `sed -i '' 's/.* = \(.*\)/\1 = \1/' filename` I advise you to try this with an expendable copy of the file first. If it doesn't work right, tell us how it went wrong, and we'll troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace text in a code file to make it easier to write then in c++ you should use `#define`.

```
#define aa printf
#define cc cout
#define ee scanf
```

(Don't forget the namespaces 'using namespace std;' which willadd the namespaces for you; Example `std::printf')

And if you are trying to read a text file from a program you should go here and use this method `http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/`. 
And then write a function to search for the character sequences line by line that you need and replace them by index.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: ty for the help but it won't work in my case or I'm too stupid to know how to do it